# Is there any chance of combing classical and non-classical logics similar to how Frege combined two logics?

Tags: logic

I have a vague understanding from listening to Prof Michael Potter that Frege was the first to succeed in combining Stoic propositional logic and Aristotelian syllogistic logic.

Is there any hope at all some massive super logic could combine classical and a- or many non-classical logics? I don’t think this is logical pluralism. Is this at all a working goal or remotely possible? Can we say it isn’t possible? It would kind of obviate some problems about one true logic and logical pluralism, and somehow outdo Frege’s feat. And if not, why not? Because they can contradict (can logics really contradict each other)? I have only learned classical logic.

Comment: I'm curious what he means by that. Frege's logic didn't use syllogisms or categorical propositions. In what sense was his logic like Aristotle's?

Comment: I agree with the comment above: Frege's logic is the first modern one in many senses; first of all because it is a cimplete system of predicate logic, including both a treatment of propositional connectives and quantifiers. If we may agree that Stoics developed (a sort of) propositional logic, Aristotle's syllogism was not exactly predicate logic: in modern sense it can be formalized as a fragment of it (nonodic predicate one).

Comment: Have you seen [SEP, Combining Logics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-combining):"The subject of combinations of logics is still a young topic in contemporary logic... Important questions... such as: “why are there so many logics instead of just one?”... can be naturally counterposed by several other questions: if there are indeed many logics, are they excluding alternatives, or are they compatible? Is it possible to combine different logics into coherent systems with the purpose of using them in applications and to shed some light on the properties of complex logics?"

Comment: @DavidGudeman if you or anyone else wants to listen to Potter’s explanation of Frege combining the two it’s in the first 20 mins (can probably skip to 12:00) of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SSezVK2PQdU

Comment: OK, I've watched it. He makes an interesting point. Stoic logic was pure propositional logic, it didn't deal with predicates or objects. Syllogistic logic had very primitive propositional combinations, but it dealt with predicates and objects. Frege combined those two features, predicates and objects were used to form propositions, which were then combined with propositional combinators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your observation about Frege is broadly correct. There were two main systems of ancient logic. One was Aristotle's syllogistic logic, which concerned the inferences that can be drawn from propositions in a simple subject-predicate form, e.g. "some S is P", "all S is P", "no S is P". The other was stoic logic, which was concerned with the connectives that stand between propositions, i.e. 'and', 'or', 'not', 'if', etc.

Throughout the medieval period, logicians used both logics but did not know how to combine them. One of Frege's insights was that we can treat "some S is P" as a conjunction: "there is some thing that is S and P", and we can treat "all S is P" as a conditional: "for any thing, if it is S then it is P". This allowed the two logics to be combined into one. Together with a much more general way of handling quantifiers, this allowed Frege's logic to become immensely more expressive and powerful than any previous logic.

But both of the ancient systems of logic share many features in common, which is why both were able to be incorporated into what we now call classical logic. The main defining features of classical logic are that it is bivalent; it includes non-contradiction, excluded middle, explosion and double negation elimination; it treats conjunction and disjunction as dual, so all four forms of de Morgan's rules hold; it treats existential and universal quantifiers as dual; it treats the entailment relation as reflexive, transitive, idempotent and monotonic.

As you are clearly aware, there are many non-classical logics that don't have all these features. Some of these are extensions of classical logic, so they combine with classical logic straightforwardly. Some are sublogics of classical logic or they have logical constants that can be directly related to those of classical logic by translation. For example, intuitionistic propositional logic can be represented within modal classical logic using the Gödel-McKinsey-Tarski translation. Other logics work quite differently and are contra-classical. These are problematic to combine with classical logic.

However, problematic does not mean impossible. Since the 1990s there has been quite a bit of work done on [combining logics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-combining/).  Some of this involves using multiple modal logics. A more general technique for combining logics is called fibring, see, e.g. [this book](https://mitpressbookstore.mit.edu/book/9780198503811) and [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266594408_Fibring_Logics).

Even so, I'm doubtful whether we will have a single one-size-fits-all logic that does everything. The range of domains of application of logic are so diverse that it just seems unlikely.

Comment: Thanks for the extra context, and exciting there is a chance yet of such a feat